# Recalibrating x and y offsets where css transforms are used

Tags: javascript, css, dom, math, matrix

I have a homemade function that gives the relative position of the mouse in relation to a specific target element (or evt.target), and a related function that gives the relative position of a DOM object in relation to a target ancestor. (bottom)

The function can handle certain CSS scale transforms, but that's it. It would be nice if someone knew precisely how I could modify the code to adjust x and y offsets for all CSS transforms. So, ideally, what I would need is:

```
curleft += obj.offsetLeft * css_transform_scale_x + css_transform_offset_x
curtop  += obj.offsetTop  * css_transform_scale_y + css_transform_offset_y
```

... just don't know how to get those scales and offsets.

Here's the current function that I'm using.

```
function getXY_zoom (evt, target) {
 if (typeof target == "undefined") target = evt.target
 if (typeof evt.pageX  != "undefined") {
  var obj = findabspos_zoom (target)
  return [evt.pageX - obj[0], evt.pageY - obj[1]]
 }
 if (typeof evt.offsetX != "undefined") return [evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY]
 if (typeof evt.layerY  != "undefined") return [evt.layerX, evt.layerY]
}

// Function to find the absolute position of a DOM object, taking CSS scale transforms into account.
function findabspos_zoom (obj, lastobj) {
 var curleft = 0, curtop = 0, zoom_level_x = 0, zoom_level_y = 0, borderWidthTest = 0
 if (typeof lastobj == "undefined") lastobj = null
 do {
  if (obj.offsetParent == lastobj) {
   zoom_level_x = 1; zoom_level_y = 1
  } else {
   zoom_level_x = getInheritedTransform(obj.offsetParent, {transform_type: "scale", xy: "x"})
   zoom_level_y = getInheritedTransform(obj.offsetParent, {transform_type: "scale", xy: "y"})
  }
  borderWidthTest = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(obj).borderLeftWidth)
  if (!isNaN(borderWidthTest)) curleft += borderWidthTest * zoom_level_x
  borderWidthTest = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(obj).borderTopWidth)
  if (!isNaN(borderWidthTest)) curtop += borderWidthTest * zoom_level_y
  if (obj.offsetParent == lastobj) return [curleft, curtop] // If offsetParent is lastobj (or null if lastobj is null), return the result.
  curleft += obj.offsetLeft * zoom_level_x
  curtop  += obj.offsetTop  * zoom_level_y
  obj = obj.offsetParent
 } while (true)
}

// Example usage: getInheritedTransform (obj, {transform_type:scale, xy:"x"})
function getInheritedTransform (obj, init) {
 var transform_type = init.transform_type
 var xy             = init.xy
 var transform_string = ""
 var transform_array  = []
 switch (transform_type) {
  case "scale":
   var scale = 1
   while (true) {
    transform_string = getTransformString ()
    if (transform_string != false) {
     transform_array = (transform_string.slice(7, transform_string.length - 6)).split(",")
     switch (xy) {
      case "x": scale *= parseFloat(transform_array[0]); break
      case "y": scale *= parseFloat(transform_array[3]); break
     }
    }
    var obj = obj.parentNode
    if (obj.parentNode == null) break
   }
  return scale
 }

 function getTransformString () {
  var transform_string = window.getComputedStyle(obj)["Transform"]
  if (typeof transform_string == "undefined") {transform_string = window.getComputedStyle(obj)["msTransform"]}
  if (typeof transform_string == "undefined") {transform_string = window.getComputedStyle(obj)["webkitTransform"]}
  if (typeof transform_string == "undefined") {transform_string = window.getComputedStyle(obj)["MozTransform"]}
  if (typeof transform_string == "undefined") {transform_string = window.getComputedStyle(obj)["OTransform"]}
  if ((typeof transform_string == "undefined") || (transform_string == "none")) return false
  return transform_string
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're approaching the problem in the wrong way.
Sometimes, the best way to solve a complicated problem is to avoid it completely.

It will be quite complex to take into account all the styles and margins and transforms to compute the coordinates.

Have you thought of adding an extra transparent layer in front of the transformed element and get the untransformed coordinates?

Comment: If the extra layer was the same nominal size? Any single transform is going to change the real offset.